# Manipulate this json string into this javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, javascript-objects

I have this json string.

```
user_json_str = 
"
[{
    "id": 1,
    "lg_name": "foo",
    "lg_password": "bar"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "lg_name": "user",
    "lg_password": "passwd"
}
]
";
```

I would like to manipulate it such that it becomes a javascript object that looks like this;

```
user_obj =
{
     foo: {
         id: 1,
         password: 'bar'
     },
     user: {
         id: 2,
         password: 'passwd'
     }
};
```

I am using node.js v4.6. I am at a loss how to begin. Some hints as starting points would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parse the string and build an object with names as key.

```js
var user_json_str = '[{"id":1,"lg_name":"foo","lg_password": "bar"},{"id":2,"lg_name": "user","lg_password":"passwd"}]',
    array = JSON.parse(user_json_str),
    object = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    object[a.lg_name] = { id: a.id, password: a.lg_password };
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.parse`, to get array of object from string.

Then, you can use `array.reduce` to loop over object and parse into necessary format.

#### Sample

```js
var user_json_str = '[{"id":1,"lg_name":"foo","lg_password": "bar"},{"id":2,"lg_name": "user","lg_password":"passwd"}]';

var object = JSON.parse(user_json_str).reduce(function (p,o) {
    p[o.lg_name] = { id: o.id, password: o.lg_password };
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, parse your array, create a new object, then loop through the array and build the object.

```
var arr = JSON.parse('[{"id": 1,"lg_name": "foo","lg_password": "bar"},{"id": 2,"lg_name": "user","lg_password": "passwd"}]');
var newObj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    newObj[arr[i].lg_name] = {id: arr[i].id, password: arr[i].lg_password}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.parse(user_json_str);